# Define a function in an SQL Navigator query

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to extract a function from a piece of SQL-code which is used multiple times in one query. I'm looking for a functionality which is similar to the following (invented by me) syntax:

```
with f(x) as (return x+1)
select f(thing1), f(thing2), f(thing3) from things
```

thing1, thing2, thing3 are integer columns in the table "things" in the example. Also, imagine that f is more complicated than an add-one function.

How do I define a function inside a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaration of a function in the `WITH` clause of a query is not possible but according to the information presented at OOW it will be in 12c version. So for now you need to create a function as a schema object whether it would be a stand-alone function or part of a package. For example:

```
create or replace function F(p_p in number)
return number
is
begin
  return p_p + 1;
end;
```

And then call it in a query, ensuring that the data type of a column you are passing in to the function as a parameter is of the same data type as the parameter of the function:

```
select f(col1)
     , f(col2)
     , ...
     , f(coln)
  from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to build a function for dynamic table and table's columns, I would do some code like this? And you cannot declare a function in the WITH clause of a query.

```
    SELECT f ( tablename,columnname1 ),
           f ( tablename,columnname2 ),
           ........
    FROM   tablename;


    Create or replace function f (tableName varchar2,ColumnName varchar2)
    Return somethingHere
    Is
        varTableName varchar2(200);
        varColumnName varchar2(200);
        varValue integer;
        t_cid           INTEGER;
        t_command       VARCHAR2(200);
    Begin
        --Get tableName
        varTableName := tableName ;
        --Get columnName
        varColumnName := ColumnName ;
        t_command := 'SELECT ' || varColumnName ||' FROM ' || varTableName;
        --Here execute dynamic sql statement
        DBMS_SQL.PARSE
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN
           DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE
        --fatch row values into varValue
        DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (..,..,varValue);
        --then do your x+1 magic here
        varValue := varValue+1
        --then output  your value.
    End;
```